# Cakephp + Not reading all unread emails using imap_open

Tags: cakephp, imap-open

I have an application in which once in 24 hours need to check mailbox and get all unread emails.

and its doing but sometime it skips 1,2 or few emails.

Can someone help me out in this regard that why its skipping ?

Comment: Please show what you tried so that people start from there

Comment: I got the clue that it was readying only those mails which have doc files in attachment and skipping pdf files. So I am installing PDF reader xpdf and then I hope i will fix it. 

Thanks for your reply